# Only the text on this button is clickable: it's body is not

Tags: silverlight

I'm very new to Silverlight and trying to create a Button with a nested TextBlock, while having both live inside a Grid. Everything works fine except only the text is clickable...

```
                    <Grid x:Name="ValueHeadingContainer" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" BorderBrush="#000" />
                        <Button Click="Button_Click" Name="ValueHeadingButton">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ValueHeadingLabel" 
                                               Text="{Binding ValueLabel}" 
                                               Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                               Style="{StaticResource FakeColumnHeader}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the textblock is clickable because you have not defined any other elements that will handle a mouse event. You need to put a wrapper around the textblock to increase the clickable surface area of your button.

I also suggest you set IsHitTestVisible on your TextBlock to false to prevent it interfering with any other mouse events.

```
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ValueHeadingLabel" 
                       IsHitTestVisible="False"
                       Text="{Binding ValueLabel}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"
                       Style="{StaticResource FakeColumnHeader}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

Comment: Wonderful! If you have time, I would appreciate a bit of explanation... how is it that the TextBlock and Border can bubble the click event up when they don't have click events? Also, why does the Border fill the entire area? I certainly appreciate your help. And if you've done any WP8 work I'm wondering how similar it is to Silverlight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a single button (not template), then it is sufficient:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Name="ValueHeadingButton">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ValueHeadingLabel" 
                                               Text="{Binding ValueLabel}" 
                                               Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                               Style="{StaticResource FakeColumnHeader}"/>
</Button>
```

I.e. you just use smth like `<Button><TextBlock></TextBlock></Button>` without content templates.